# Largest Permutation using Stack or Queue

Tags: stack, queue, permutation

So this is a homework question and it asks to design an algorithm that finds the largest permutation given n, an array, A that contains the letters I and D or length n, and produces S, an array of n + 1  such that  each integer in {0 ... n} appears exactly once.

In the array A, I represents increasing and D represents decreasing.

So the examples given are
if n= 4 and A=IIID then S= 1;2;3;4;0
if n= 6 and A=IDIDID then S= 5;6;3;4;1;2;0 as it is larger than S= 5;6;2;4;1;3;0

The algorithm also needs to run in O(n) time.

I'm currently stuck on how I would write the pseudocode for this problem using a Stack or a Queue as required in the question

Comment: I've thought of using the number of I's and D's in a row to determine which number to add next but the algorithm needs to be in O(n) so that wouldn't work.  So far that's really the only thing I managed to come up with that could potentially work without the O(n) restriction.

Answer (score 0):

First I will explain the solution without any stack or queue, then we can integrate them in our solution, since we have `n+1` elements i will consider the last element of the array to be `D`.

So we can divide the elements of the array in 2 parts one containing all the increasing elements and the other the decreasing elements. So if we have `k` D's in our array the first k elements would belong to the first part, i.e `0, 1, 2, 3.....,(k-1)` next `((n+1) - k)` would be the second part and represent the I's.

Now if we have a sequence of D's like `DDD` we would take the elements from the first part i.e (k-1), (k-2), (k-3).

If we have a sequence of I's like `III` we would take the elements from the second part i.e `((n+1)-2), ((n+1)-1), (n+1)`.

Lets explain it with an example :

`A : IIIDDIDDDIID    //I have added the last D`

`n = 11`

`A1 : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

`A2 : 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11`

First we have `III`, we place `9, 10, 11` from the second part.
Then we have `DD` we place `5, 4` just like we discussed in the above part, then we have a `I` we would then place `8` from the second part and so on.

Continuing the above we have : `9, 10, 11, 5, 4, 8, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 0`

Algorithm :

> For the `A1` part of the array we will keep a stack `S1` and when we need the elements we will pop from the stack.
>
> For the `A2` part of the array we will keep 2 stacks `S2` and `S3`, `S2` contains the entire `A2` array initially, and `S3` would be empty initially. So if I have `x` I's then I can pop `x` elements from the `S2` stack and add it to the `S3` and finally pop the entire `S3` stack to get the answer.

using the above example :

`A : IIIDDIDDDID`

`S1 : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

`S2 : 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11`

`S3 : EMPTY`

1) Pop `S2` 3 times and place the elements in `S3` then the stack has

`S2 : 6, 7, 8`

`S3 : 11, 10, 9`

2) Pop `S3` and place in the answer.

`S3 : EMPTY`

`ANS : 9, 10, 11`

3) Pop S1 2 times and place in the answer.

`S2 : 0, 1, 2, 3`

`ANS : 9, 10, 11, 5, 4`

And so on...